# Visibility of symmetry in a link diagram

Tags: knot-theory

In "The First 1,701,936 Knots" it says that "any symmetry of a prime alternating link must be visible, up to flypes, in any alternating diagram of the link."

What is the formal definition of the visibility of symmetry in a link diagram?